# how to find half edge boundary faces/twins

Tags: algorithm, 3d, mesh, polygons, edges

I've implemented a catmull clark subdivision algorithm that uses half edges for everything except the boundary edges. The boundary edges have a twin pointing to null. The thing works, and i get exactly the expected results, but the bits of literature that i found seem to mention that all edges are double edges, and i assume the boundary null face has a loop that is connected with prev / next.

My algorithm is roughly:

1. Loop through all polygons

   1. loop through all vertices
   2. make an edge with vertex and next vertex in polygon and push it to array
   3. connect the prev and next edges ( calculate indecis based on vert num )
   4. write the edge index into a map edgeA->edgeB->edgeIndex
2. Loop through all edges

   1. look up `edgeMap[edgeA][edgeB]` and `edgeMap[edgeB][edgeA]`
   2. if found, connect those two edges, else assign `twin->null`

The idea i have is to push all such edges that have a null twin into an array during the second step. Pick any edge from that array, and loop around it's vertex until another edge with a null twin is hit. Every time, remove that edge from the boundary array, create new twins, and compute the next for the starting twin, and prev for the next twin. When the first selected edge from the array is encountered again, that boundary is complete, pick any remaining edge in the array if there are any left and repeat.

Is this a good idea? I notice that at a minimum, when looping around vertices, i have to do two comparisons - if the starting edge is encountered, but also for `twin->null`. I've read somewhere that a bit of memory can be saved if storing the twins one after another in the array, but i've no idea how to achieve that. My edge list is basically loop after loop for each polygon. This way i can assign the prev and next indecis when creating each edge.

How could i easily find all boundary faces if all of the edges point to null? If they shouldn't be pointing to null, how to manage indecis, since it seems that there would be an overlap with the polygon list?